# CreateMany generates null values when using partially filled objects in a With clause

Tags: c#, autofixture

Having the code below, I'm generating 2 student objects using `CreateMany(2)`. `Country` must be `"England"` for both objects. The other `SchoolId` must be unique.

But the `students` variable below contains `School` objects with `null` as SchoolId, while I expect unique values there. What am I doing wrong? Or am I missing some extra configuration?

```
using AutoFixture;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        var students = fixture
            .Build<Student>()
            .With(st => st.School, new School
            {
                //SchoolId = Expecting AutoFixture would generate a unique SchoolId here
                Country = "England"
            })
            .CreateMany(2).ToList();

        foreach (var schoolId in students.Select(x => x.School.SchoolId))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"schoolId: {schoolId ?? "null"}");
        }
    }
}

public class Student
{
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public School School { get; set; }
}

public class School
{
    public string SchoolId { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `foreach` you are selecting `SchoolId`, but you haven't specified what `AutoFixture` should use for it so it's just `null`.
You can do the below:

```
var students = fixture
    .Build<Student>()
    .With(st => st.School, new School
    {
        SchoolId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        Country = "England"
    })
    .CreateMany(2).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not using the default `AutoFixture` way of configuring properties. I'm expecting a value like `SchoolId848da9e2-a01b-46a8-bb22-4a5a42c8aa10`. I can indeed mimic that. But shouldn't this behaviour be the default, without me specifying `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`? Assume there are tens of properties like that, do I have to specify `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` on all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Here I have a possible solution, but I'm thinking there must be simpler way to do it.

```
var students = fixture
    .Build<Student>()
    .With(p => p.School, (IFixture f) => f.Build<School>().With(sc => sc.Country, "England").Create())
    .CreateMany(2).ToList();
```

Comment: But this way you end up with a different `SchoolId` for each `Student` and I assume you want to have the same Id as the `School` is the same.

Comment: @IvanGechev, No, I will have two `Students` and they go to different `Schools`. There is no parent child relation here, just one to one.

Comment: But why then have all schools named "Oxford" but with different IDs?

Comment: I adjusted my example.

Comment: For your updated answer, I think this is the best solution.